# Can't align a button next to a div

Tags: html, css

I can get the button div to align to the right. but I can't get it in the middle of the div. Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly. I have tried vertically align but it still does not seem to help.

Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">


.glow {
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color:#000000;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding: 15px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
border-left-width: 3px;
border-left-color: aqua;
border-left-style: inset;
width: 90%;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px 
rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}

.button{
    width:20%;
    padding-bottom:24px; 
    float:right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="glow">
<div style="width: 70%;" class="mktoText" mktoname="Text" id="text2">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                          </div>
<div class="button">BUTTON HERE</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you'll never have to worry about things like this again:

```css
.glow {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
            align-items:center;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;    
    justify-content: space-around;

    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: aqua;
    border-left-style: inset;
    width: 90%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px 
    rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px 
    rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}

.button{
    width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="glow">
   <div style="width: 70%;" class="mktoText" mktoname="Text" id="text2">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
<div class="button">BUTTON HERE</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `text-align:center;` to the button and it worked for the button to take it to the center of the div.

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .glow {
        font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        padding: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        border-left-width: 3px;
        border-left-color: aqua;
        border-left-style: inset;
        width: 90%;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    }

    .button {
        width: 20%;
        padding-bottom: 24px;
        float: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="glow">
        <div style="width: 70%;" class="mktoText" mktoname="Text" id="text2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
                ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">BUTTON HERE</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure. 

make my answer accepted or upvote it if u think it was a minimalistic solution. .

Answer (score 0):

to make `vertical-align: middle;` work, set `display: table;` for parent and `display: table-cell;` for child

```css
.glow {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding: 15px;
  display: table;
  text-align: left;
  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-left-color: aqua;
  border-left-style: inset;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}

.button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="glow">
  <div class="mktoText" mktoname="Text" id="text2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">BUTTON HERE</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use flex properties for aligning exactly aligning center.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.glow {
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color:#000000;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding: 15px;
/* display: inline-block;  */
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: left;
border-left-width: 3px;
border-left-color: aqua;
border-left-style: inset;
width: 90%;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 10px 
rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}

.button {
      width: 20%;
    /* padding-bottom: 24px; */
    /* float: right; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="glow">
    <div style="width: 70%;" class="mktoText" mktoname="Text" id="text2">
     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
      amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
      tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim 
      ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
      lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  <div class="button">BUTTON HERE</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```